# HttpWebRequest - C# - Post with Certificate.crt + private.key

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, private-key, x509certificate2

How can I send a certificate with Private.key?
I am sending only the certificate and it returns a 403 Forbidden error.

[Certificate + Private.key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6p7X.png)

[GetAccessToken Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0llnE.png)

[PegarCertificadoServicoPeloIndividuo - Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGKFo.png)

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem with this API.

To solve it, I had to ''merge'' the two files (.crt and .key).

For this, it is necessary to download a program, follow this link: https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html . I downloaded the exe from the first line from that link.

After merging the .crt and .key files, you'll get a .pfx file, that's what you'll use in code to make the call to the API.

Hope this helps